# Adjusted Chi-square test or standard Chi-square test for clustered data?

Tags: chi-squared-test, cluster-sample

I am performing a risk factor analysis of the individual and household-level factors associated with *Plasmodium* infection in individuals located in 8 villages in Cambodia.

I want to perform an initial statistical test to determine if there are significant differences in infection prevalence in different categorical exposure groups: "having slept under a bed net last night", for example.

Other papers have used the standard Chi-square test, yet that assumes independence, which is violated when I have clustered data. Reading around the subject, I have seen suggestions that the **adjusted Chi-square** test might be appropriate in this situation, for that does not assume independence.

Is that the right approach in this situation?

Comment: You need to adjust for clustering of people in houses because (as you say) you have violated independence. I also wonder about your villages - should you incorporate these strata into the analysis. (You can do this with, for example, the survey package in R.)

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thank you for your response. So, to clarify, in your opinion, am I right to use the adjusted Chi-square test for this simple association testing? To your follow-up question - in the later detailed analysis, I am running a mixed effects model with a random intercept for each household but with village as a fixed effect. Thanks again

Comment: Yes,the adjusted chi-square and mixed effects model are generally very similar, but they make slightly different assumptions.  So adjusted is the way to go, but I'd consider village as strata - but I don't know a huge amount about this (which is why I commented, not answered). You might want to find someone who actually knows that they are talking about.

Comment: Thank you for the help Jeremy - I am learning all the time!